# How could a person correct their vision with limited technology?

Tags: humans, medieval

I'm brainstorming a character (human) and I was thinking about how they would correct their vision if they were short/long-sighted. I would assume that the poorer people would just deal with their bad vision for the whole of their lives, but what about the rich? My character is a prince so would have access to anything he wanted. Yet it's set in a medieval-like world. What kind of ways were there to correct vision, if anything?

Comment: & glasses aren't' an option because?

Comment: The Secret of Kells is a fun movie, and turns around one solution to this problem: enter the temple of the Old God and steal his eye to augment your own.

Comment: They had eye glasses in the Middle Ages. [Here is a 14th century picture](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:38_Ugo_da_San_Caro.jpg) of the 13th century cardinal Hugues of Saint Cher wearing eye glasses.

Comment: Just be careful:  myopia or presbyopia are the cases where the lens produces a good image but not at the retina.  The posted answers solve this.  However, if the retina itself is a mess, such as in nystigmatic patients,  we still don't have good ways of correcting such problems.

Comment: Emotionally an mentally healthy people have a healthy vision as well. Send them to eye-doctor and to treatment for emotional and mental healing.

Comment: The Manga Dr Stone, does a great job of coming up with a stone age solution, A thick walled gourd helmet with pinholes for eyes, it severely limits field of vision but drastically improves the clarity of vision.

Comment: @John I haven't read the manga, is it different than in the anime where they stick lenses in the gourd?  One think Dr Stone (and a lot of people) gets wrong is the idea that everyone had to put up with nearsightedness in old times. The truth is, almost no one had it. Recent research in developing nations shows it comes mostly from school, your eyes don't develop properly when the horizon is a wall a few feet away, instead of miles away.  The poor prince in the above story would only have it BECAUSE he was a prince, and had the privilege of education.

Comment: @CaptainSkyfish Its more common now,  that is very different than saying it never happened. It still effects around 4% of even low tech native populations. There is a both genetic and environmental causes, you will still have many people with eye problems. Don't fall for sensationalist media that likes to find bullshit single causes for complex problems. Many will have it regardless of environment, many people will still have to put with it . Also yes it is the same anime, the gourd is the native solution but the scientist of the story makes glass lens, giving her full range of vision.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Eye glasses, just as we use today

They had eye glasses in the Middle Ages. Here is a 14th century picture of the 13th century cardinal Hugh of Saint Cher wearing eye glasses:

[image: Cardinal Hugh of Saint Cher (1200-1263), wearing eye glasses]

*Cardinal [Hugh of Saint Cher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugh_of_Saint-Cher) (1200-1263), wearing eye glasses. Portrait from the monastery of Saint Nicholas, Treviso, 1352. One of the oldest depictions of a person wearing eye glasses. Photograph by Risorto Celebrano, available on Wikimedia under the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported license.*

[Medieval eye glasses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasses#Invention) were of the ["pince-nez"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pince-nez) type; our more common type with temples which hook on the ears became common in the Renaissance.

By the 14th century eye glasses had become sufficiently common so that, for example, [Francesco Petrarca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrarch) could boast in a letter that he had had no need for eye glasses before the age of 60, showing that he expected the readers to be aware that older people needed eye glasses.

Answer (score 17):

## ᐃᓪᒑᒃ

*(ilgaak)*

**He could wear "glasses" that work by using slits or holes through an opaque material.**

Quite feasible given your level of technology is a device called [*ilgaak*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_goggles), which as you can see, is a pair of slit goggles. Having no way of making clear lenses, the Inuit did the next best thing, which was to make use of the pinhole effect.  Ilgaak serve as snow goggles, the narrow slit keeping snow and wind out of the eyes, and help clarify vision by darkening the inner surface and only allowing vision through a very thin opening.

[image]

A more conventional device would be the [*stenopeic glasse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_glasses), which as you can see, also operate on the pinhole effect. [Visual acuity is (slightly) improved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_occluder) and is well within the technological capabilities of your culture.

[image]

There is also the best of both worlds, the pinhole spectacle. Inuit design meets Spanish cool in the antojos of Daza de Valdés. His spectacles are composed to two opaque "lenses" with horizontal pinholes drilled through the matrix, all set into a standard spectacles frame. [This article](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/opo.12594) describes the effect and uses in more detail.

[image]

Comment: @nick012000 --- Those aren't "broken characters". That's the name of the thing.

Comment: They weren't English characters and didn't seem to be displaying properly for me. If you want to edit it to have the name of the device written with English characters, go ahead.

Comment: Yeah, could be a display issue. The letters, though obviously not English, worked for me. Edited, but I kept your revision.

Comment: My impression is that ilgaak are *not* doing any optical correction and are used to prevent snow blindness.  Can you give some reference that shows they allow corrections to vision ?

Comment: I'm pretty short sighted. A quick experiment with a piece of paper and a few holes definitely gives an improvement to my vision, though not enough to correct my sight completely

Comment: These are called "raster googles" (at least a friend of mine that uses them calls them so). They have the advantage of correcting almost all vision defects related to focus (short, long-sightedness, astigmatism, other deformations) to a great extent with rather minor side effects. Then again, I think they were invented long after the glass lenses.

Comment: Ilgaak were only used as protection against snow blindness, not in any way to improve vision beyond that. Source: the Inuit elders I live among.

Comment: @KeithMorrison Right, but they have (minor) vision correction as a nice side effect.

Comment: @StephenG -- Correct, their original purpose is to keep snow out. That said, the narrowness of the slit does create a pinhole effect and thus affords the same kind of correction the other device does.

Comment: @Riddles -- Indeed -- the effect isn't going to completely cure you! (Though, in the past, a number of quacks promised just this kind of cure with pinhole spectacles.

Comment: @KeithMorrison -- I don't disagree with you, however, many tools designed for a certain purpose end up being useful for other purposes!

Comment: slit glasses don't create a pinhole effect, becasue they are not a pinhole, there is a still a wide angle of waves being allowed in. the pinhole effect requires a narrow tube to isolate the waves to all being parallel. you can recreate the effect with your hand.

Comment: @John -- It's just a long pinhole. The idea is to sort of allow only a certain angle of light into the eye. Whether it's a single hole, multiple holes or a slit or a slit-like line of pinholes, it's all the same effect. Same effect as squinting.

Comment: @elemtilas no a long pin hole would be a tube which will work, as will a row of pin holes. Slits do not work, because they are nor forcing rays of light to be parallel.

Comment: Slits work fine in one axis. If oriented in the right direction they work to correct astigmatism. Easy enough to verify for yourself if you have astigmatism: look at a [test image](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vision/astigtest.html) with one eye, then make a "slit" with the edge of your hands held near that eye. If the slit is aligned along the axis where the lines look most blurry, the astigmatism goes away.

Comment: @John - Maybe we're talking at cross purposes. Anyway, the end result is the same!

Answer (score 14):

He can just use glasses.

Ptolemy (c. 100-170 CE) described the use of convex lenses for magnification. Reading stones were in use in Europe around 1000. Eyeglasses were being made in Northern Italy by around 1290: a sermon in 1306 mentioned it hadn't yet been 20 years since eyeglasses were invented.

Given that glass was in widespread production and use in the Roman Empire, and had been produced by humans for a few thousand years at that point, it's simple to imagine some bright spark fooling around with lenses and realizing that if you took a pair of small ones and mounted them in front of the eyes, you could help people with poor vision. Technologically, all you need is the ability to make clear glass and then grind and polish it into a lens, and skill in fine metalwork to make some sort of frame. There's no particular reason why the Romans couldn't have done it, which means there's no reason why they couldn't be available in a medieval world with similar technology.

Comment: depending on how portable you you want them, single lens magnifiers have been around since the BC's

Answer (score 1):

Maybe goggles filled with a liquid. If the refractive index of the liquid was carefully chosen it could compensate for the eye's focal length. This could work because the cornea accounts for approximately two-thirds of the eye's total optical power.